# how to integrate multiple widgets (xtypes) in one page

Tags: javascript, extjs, widget, aem

I have a requirement, which requires me to create a page(as like siteadmin, dam pages) in CQ with two tabs. Each tab should have a different xtype(siteadmin, useradmin).

I have included these two xtypes. Any one of the xtype is rendering since the both CQ.wcm.SiteAdmin and CQ.security.UserAdmin xtypes are extending same CQ.Ext.Viewport class as per CQ widget API, There should only be one Viewport(xtype) created in a page.

But page has two ViewPorts(siteadmin,useradmin). 
I don’t know anything about EXT JS. Can some one point me on how to integrate multiple widgets (xtypes) and integrate them into one page/application.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, could you provide some code replicating the issue so that we can see what you've got so far?

Comment: updated it. Please check it once

Answer (score 0):

You will find the [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started) a useful starting place.

In particular the App Architecture tutorials (all three parts) walk through how to create multiple custom widgets (xtypes) and integrate them into one application.